# Javascript - Permalinks converting

Tags: javascript, replace, permalinks

I use JavaScript to convert my string to a nice permalink for URL, but i have a small problem when i use duble or more space its convert it to -- and more, if i use it in the end of this string its replace it to - to, like this

```
this---is---a-test-right-now----
```

the string i want to have back if i got this is follow

```
this-is-a-test-right-now
```

can sombardy help me here?

my own Javascript look like this

```
function prototype( str )
{
    var ret = str;
    ret = ret.replace( /ø/g, 'oe' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Ø/g, 'OE' );
    ret = ret.replace( /å/g, 'aa' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Å/g, 'AA' );
    ret = ret.replace( /æ/g, 'ae' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Æ/g, 'AE' );
    ret = ret.replace( /\_/g, '-' );

    ret = ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/-]/ig,'-').replace(/_+/ig,'-').toLowerCase();

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one more replace in chain will get the job done, by looking for occurrence of `-` more than twice to replace by one `-`

```
replace(/[-]{2,}/g, '-')
```

The above example will look for the occurence of `-` more than twice and replace it with single `-` and do it `globally` to achieve it

```
function prototype( str )
{
    var ret = str;
    ret = ret.replace( /ø/g, 'oe' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Ø/g, 'OE' );
    ret = ret.replace( /å/g, 'aa' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Å/g, 'AA' );
    ret = ret.replace( /æ/g, 'ae' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Æ/g, 'AE' );
    ret = ret.replace( /\_/g, '-' );

    ret = ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/-]/ig,'-').replace(/_+/ig,'-').replace(/[-]{2,}/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to replace any consecutive occurrences with a single dash instead of replacing every occurrence with dashes.

```
ret = ret.replace(/[^a-z0-9_\/]+/ig,'-').replace(/-+$/,'').toLowerCase();
```

The second regex gets rid of trailing dashes.

Also note that `A-Z` is unnecessary since the `i` modifier makes the regex case-insensitive. You could also shorten the previous lines to e.g. `ret = ret.replace( /[æÆ]/g, 'ae' )` since you're converting the string to lowercase anyway.